# export filtered messages list to excelsheet

Tags: thunderbird

I have searched few mails from my sent folder. I want to save the result in an excel sheet. I only want the subject, and time in the excelsheet (content of mail is not necessary)
How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried the [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) add-on?

Comment: As I need only subject,date,sender etc not the full content this tool will not work for me